# How to record a video in portrait orientation?

Tags: c#, video, camera, windows-phone-8.1, media

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 which uses MediaCapture class to record videos. I want to give user freedom to record video in either portrait or landsapce by just rotating the device. Please note my app has fixed portrait orientation. Due to fixed orientation, I am using OrientationChanged event of class SimpleOrientationSensor.

Now I have noticed that the portait video recorded in default camera app and in my app has some differences. You can see the difference in below given images. All the videos are in 720p resolution. The player images are of portrait locked orientation. The code is also given below. Can any one explain me what's wrong with my code to record the portrait video? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

```
MediaCaptureInitializationSettings set;
MediaCapture _camCapture;
VideoRotation videoRotation = VideoRotation.None;
bool _isRecording = false;

// Camera resource disposal is handled properly
private async Task InitializeCamera()
{
    try
    {
        if (set == null)
        {
            set = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();

            DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

            if (deviceID != null)
            {
                set.VideoDeviceId = deviceID.Id;
            }
        }

        _camCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await _camCapture.InitializeAsync(set);
        VideoView.Source = _camCapture;    //VideoView is CaptureElement object in XAML
        _camCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
        await _camCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private async void OrientationChanged(object sender, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            DetectCurrentOrintation(e.Orientation);
        }); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private void DetectCurrentOrintation(SimpleOrientation orientation)
{
    try
    {
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                videoRotation = VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
                break;
            case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                videoRotation = VideoRotation.None;
                break;
            case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                videoRotation = VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees;
                break;
            case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                videoRotation = VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private async void btnRecordVideo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!_isRecording)
        {
            var _videoRecording = await MyFolderInLocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("testRecord.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            MediaEncodingProfile mEncode = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

            _isRecording = true;

            //Two videos are with SetRecordRotation(value) and 
            //for two other I commeted out the line.
            _camCapture.SetRecordRotation(videoRotation);
            await _camCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(mEncode, _videoRecording);
        }
        else
        {
            await _camCapture.StopRecordAsync();
            _isRecording = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Question updated fully with the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample on the Microsoft github page that is relevant, although they target Windows 10. Still, the APIs should work on 8/8.1.

[UniversalCameraSample](http://aka.ms/2015builduniversalcamerasample): This one captures videos and supports portrait and landscape orientations. Here is the relevant part:

```
// Create storage file in Pictures Library
var videoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("SimpleVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

var encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

// Calculate rotation angle, taking mirroring into account if necessary
var rotationAngle = 360 - ConvertDeviceOrientationToDegrees(GetCameraOrientation());
encodingProfile.Video.Properties.Add(RotationKey, PropertyValue.CreateInt32(rotationAngle));

await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, videoFile);
```

Have a closer look at the sample to see how to get the orientation of the camera in the first place (a call to it is being made in the snippet I posted). You generally don't want to call SetRecordRotation (or SetPreviewRotation) because those have a perf impact over just adding rotation metadata.

Watch the [camera session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-730) from the recent //build/ conference, which includes a little bit of a walkthrough through some camera samples and gives you more context around the sample.